# Julia: Is it possible to create a string by reinterpreting a piece of memory as a string?

Tags: string, julia

I can use `unsafe_string` to create a string. But after doing that the pointer of the string is different to the location of the ptr `unsafe_string(ptr)`.

How do I create a string without copying the content at `ptr`? And instead of point to it?

```
a = "def"
b  = unsafe_string(pointer(a))

pointer(a) 
pointer(b) # not the same as above.
```

I want `pointer(b) == pionter(a)` to be true and `b == a` to be true!

I don't need interned strings. I basically, have a bunch of memory that's already in string form, so I just need to point to it.

So solutions like

```
b = intern(a)
```

is NOT what I am looking for. I am looking to create strings from memory. Not to reduce duplication.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "already in string form", is it a Julia String object or C-style String?

Maybe this snippet helps:

```
a = "def"
b = unsafe_pointer_to_objref(pointer_from_objref(a))

pointer(a) 
pointer(b) # now it is the same
```

Comment: The problem is that is't NOT already a string. It's just a string in  binary form and it's not in the form of a string.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more about your usage? Julia String is somewhat kind of "owned" type. If you want to operate on a memory buffer, `Cstring` or `Vector{UInt8}` might be better.

Comment: this contains more descriptions https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-do-make-a-string-from-pointer-to-a-piece-memory-that-is-in-the-format-of-a-string/28534